# How to remove redundant <p> and <br/> from the result of WordPress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I use shortcode to output the following html in a variable, but there are too many redundant code such as br and p tags, how to remove them? Thanks!

**My shortcode function:**

```
add_shortcode('portfolios', 'van_portfolios_shortcode');
function van_portfolios_shortcode( $atts, $content) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'number'=>'9',
        'slug'=>''
    ), $atts)); 
   $str=van_portfolios($slug,$number,false);
   return $str;
}

function van_process_shortcode($content) {
    global $shortcode_tags;
    // Backup current registered shortcodes and clear them all out
    $orig_shortcode_tags = $shortcode_tags;
    $shortcode_tags = array();
    add_shortcode('portfolios', 'van_portfolios_shortcode');

    // Do the shortcode (only the one above is registered)
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    // Put the original shortcodes back
    $shortcode_tags = $orig_shortcode_tags;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'van_process_shortcode', 7);
```

**Correct makeup is**

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
           <a class="overlay" href="#">
             <h3>...</h3>
             <p>...</p>
           </a>
           <div class="tools"><a href="#" class="zoomin" rel="lightbox">ZoomIn</a><a href="#" class="info">Info</a></div>
           <a href="#" class="item">...</a>
         </div>
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
           <a class="overlay" href="#">
             <br /><!--This <br />is redundant code-->
             <h3>...</h3>
             <p>...</p><p><!--This <p> is redundant code-->
           </a>
           <div class="tools"><a href="#" class="zoomin" rel="lightbox">ZoomIn</a><a href="#" class="info">Info</a></div>
           <p><!--This <p> is redundant code--><a href="#" class="item">...</a>
         </div>
```

Comment: You could print out each HTML page on paper and then use a textmarker of some kind to mark each `<br>` and `<p>` and use a sharp scissor to cut them out ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this code before content is displayed:

**UPDATED**

```
// From your question 
$content = do_shortcode($content);
// Put the original shortcodes back
$shortcode_tags = $orig_shortcode_tags;

// Add this code 
$content = preg_replace( '%<p>&nbsp;\s*</p>%', '', $content ); // Remove all instances of "<p>&nbsp;</p>" to avoid extra lines.
$Old     = array( '<br />', '<br>' );
$New     = array( '','' );
$content = str_replace( $Old, $New, $content );

// From your question
return $content;
```

Comment: I tried your method but It still generate <p><br/>, and others shortcodes is become invalid.

Comment: Thank you very much.Inspired by your codes, I just replaced the_content() to echo do_shortcode(get_the_content()), the problem is solved! Thank you again.